# ¿Hay alguna forma de desactivar los Listenes/Eventos y luego volver a activarlos?

Tags: java, java-swing, mouselistener

Tengo compontes, que usan varios oyentes ( `MouseListener` ,  `MouseWheelListener` ,  `FocusListener` ,  `KeyListener` , etc),
pero solo necesito que funcionen en determinadas ocasiones, podría poner una condicional dentro de los propios oyentes, así no se ejecuta el código que tienen que activar, aunque el oyente esté funcionando, pero estaría bueno saber si hay alguna forma de desactivar/deshabilitar temporalmente los mismos cuando no se necesiten, para ahorrar recursos. Desconozco si hay alguna forma de hacerlo pero se me ocurrió que podría eliminar dichos oyentes del componente y después volver a agregarlos, aunque no creo que sea muy eficiente hacerlo, sin contar que tendría que poder acceder al objeto del oyente para poder agregarlo luego, de vuelta.

Un ejemplo de uno de estos componentes:

```java
package interfaz.principal;

import java.awt.AWTKeyStroke;

       public Eventos() {

           accionCrearCmpMouseDondeElCursor();
           atajosDelTeclado();
           accionCrearCmpTeclado();

       }

       private void accionCrearCmpMouseDondeElCursor() {

           addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
               @Override
               public void mouseReleased(final MouseEvent e) {

                   tiempoPresCmpt = tiempoPresCmpt - MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getTEMPORIZADOR().getTiempoEnMilisegundos();
               
               }

               @Override
               public void mousePressed(final MouseEvent e) {
                   System.out.println("Asdasdssda");
                   if (!MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getGRABAR().isEnabled()) { // Esta puesto para evitar ciertos bugs

                       requestFocus();

                       final Click NUEVO;

                       if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e)) {

                           NUEVO = new ClickDerecho(e.getXOnScreen() - 15, e.getYOnScreen() - 20, obtenerDelay());

                       } else {

                           NUEVO = new ClickIzquierdo(e.getXOnScreen() - 15, e.getYOnScreen() - 20, obtenerDelay());

                       }
                   
                       tiempoPresCmpt = MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getTEMPORIZADOR().getTiempoEnMilisegundos();

                       registrarYAnadirNuevoComponente(NUEVO);

                   }

               }

           });

           addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {

               @Override
               public void mouseWheelMoved(final MouseWheelEvent e) {

                   if (!MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getCOMBOBOX().getMENU().isShowing() && siNoHayUnCmpDondeEstaElCursor()
                           && cantidadDeRotacionesEnUnTiempo == 0) {

                       cantidadDeRotacionesEnUnTiempo++;
                       iniciarCuentaRegresiva();

                       final Rueda AGREGAR;

                       if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0) {

                           AGREGAR = new DesplazamientoArriba(e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen(), obtenerDelay());

                       } else {

                           AGREGAR = new DesplazamientolAbajo(e.getXOnScreen(), e.getYOnScreen(), obtenerDelay());

                       }

                       registrarYAnadirNuevoComponente(AGREGAR);

                   }

               }

           });

       }

       private void accionCrearCmpTeclado() {

           addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

               @Override
               public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                   
                   registrarYAnadirNuevoComponente(new Tecla(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x,
                           MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y, obtenerDelay(), e.getKeyCode()));

               }

           });

       }

       private void atajosDelTeclado() {

           addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

               @Override
               public void keyPressed(final KeyEvent e) {

                   AWTKeyStroke ak = AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStrokeForEvent(e);

                   if (ak.equals(AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK))) { // ctrl+z

                       GESTOR_DE_COMPONENTESLAMINA.retroceder();

                   } else if (ak.equals(AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Y, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK))) { // ctrl+y
                                                                                                                   // para
                       GESTOR_DE_COMPONENTESLAMINA.avanzar();

                   } else {

                       switch (e.getKeyCode()) {

                       case KeyEvent.VK_HOME:
                           MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getGRABAR().doClick();
                           break;

                       case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, KeyEvent.VK_INSERT, KeyEvent.VK_PAUSE:

                           if (MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getPAUSA().isEnabled()) { // Revisar

                               MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getPAUSA().doClick();

                           } else {

                               MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getEJECUTAR().doClick();

                           }

                           break;

                       case KeyEvent.VK_PAGE_UP, KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:
                           MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getDETENER().doClick();
                           break;

                       }

                   }

               }

           });

       }

       private int obtenerDelay() {
           return Math.abs(MouseClicker.FLOTANTE.getTEMPORIZADOR().getTiempoEnMilisegundos()
                   - (COMPONENTES_ACTUALES_EN_CONTENEDOR.isEmpty() ? 0
                           : COMPONENTES_ACTUALES_EN_CONTENEDOR.getLast().getLapsoDeTiempo()));
       }

       private boolean siNoHayUnCmpDondeEstaElCursor() {
           return JPanel.class.isAssignableFrom(
                   getContentPane().getComponentAt(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()).getClass());
       }

       private void iniciarCuentaRegresiva() {

           try {

               if (tiempoRegresivo.alive()) {

                   tiempoRegresivo.kill();

               }

           } catch (final NullPointerException e) {

           }

           tiempoRegresivo = new Timer(0, 0, 1, new Consumer<Object>() {

               @Override
               public void accept(final Object a) {

                   cantidadDeRotacionesEnUnTiempo = 0;

               }

           });

           tiempoRegresivo.init();

       }

   }

}
```

Comment: No es precisamente un [Ejemplo Mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), si reduces el código a lo esencial será más fácil responderte.

Comment: Sal - Corregido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que tu clase es subclase de `Component`, sólo tendrías que sobre-escribir el método que procesa el tipo de evento para interceptarlo; puede ser conveniente usar una variable (ej. `boolean eventos;`) para controlar el comportamiento. Por ejemplo, para controlar eventos de la rueda del ratón:

```
boolean conEventos = true;

@Override
protected void processMouseWheelEvent( MouseWheelEvent me ){
    if( !this.conEventos )
        return;
    super.processMouseWheelEvent(me);
}
```

Comment: Me sirvió, gracias Sal.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día, creo que perfectamente, como decís, podes eliminar y volver a agregar los listeners cuando lo necesites.

Un ejemplo que funciona por si te sirve: es un mismo boton de login que dice login (si esta deslogueado) o logout (si esta logueado). Por lo que el click sobre ese boton debe hacer 2 cosas distintas según su estado.

En el siguiente codigo en un estado apaga un listener y prende otro y en el otro estado hace lo opuesto:

```
function DisplayNoLogueado(){
document.querySelector(".login-name").textContent = "";
const loginButton = document.querySelector(".login-button");
loginButton.textContent = "Login";
loginButton.removeEventListener("click", Desloguearse);
loginButton.addEventListener("click", SolicitarLogin);}


function DisplayLogueado(usuario){
document.querySelector(".login-name").textContent = usuario;
const loginButton = document.querySelector(".login-button");
loginButton.textContent = "Logout";
loginButton.removeEventListener("click", SolicitarLogin);
loginButton.addEventListener("click", Desloguearse);}
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: OP hizo su pregunta acerca de Java. Esto es JS...

Comment: Tenes razón! Disculpas.

Comment: Lo tendre en cuenta. Gracias Pablo.